# Determinant of 4x4 matrix equals determinant of 3x3 matrix... but how does this work?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, circles, triangles

I found this 4x4 matrix on wikipedia. It's determinant is used to tell if a vector D in R2 lies inside, outside or on the circumcircle of a triangle ABC.

[image: 4x4 matrix determinant]

What I fail to understand is:

Why does the determinant of the 4x4 matrix equal the determinant of the simpler 3x3 matrix and why does it seem to make no difference if you say (A^2 - D^2) or (A - D)^2 in this case?

Thanks for your answers, I'm just beginning to learn linear algebra.

Have a nice day!

PS

this is the link to the wikipedia article
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Subtracting one row from another does not change the determinant. Apply this rule three times to see that 
   subtracting the last row from the others leaves a matrix whose last column has three $0$ and one $1$. Then apply Laplace expansion on the last column.
2. Subtract $2D_x$ times the first column from the third column. 
   Subtract $2D_y$ times the second column from the third column.

Comment: which rule does this follow? I thought you can only substract one row from another.

Comment: @Peter It’s the second point of his reply, $(A - D)^2 = A^2 - D^2 - 2D(A - D)$.

Comment: @k.stm I see, thank you.